# xulrunner, C#: how to change html?

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio-2015, xulrunner, geckofx

I moved my project to custom WebBrowser and I choose XULRunner. I am use XULRunner 33 and GeckoFX 33. So, I adding it in project and initialize it.

In my program I use custom html scenaries, but how I can change html?
WebBrowser example is: `webBrowser1.DocumentText = "html code here";`
But XULRunner have only Document (read only), DocumentTitle, DomDocument (also), Text (doesn't affect) and I can't use it to change html. How it is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Geckofx 33 have the LoadHtml method instead of the DocumentText. So, for example:

```
geckoWebBrowser.LoadHtml("html code here", "url of a page here");
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what I need and don't found. Now question can be closed.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, html is modified with some kind of scripting language, and XUL supports [scripting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/script). According to [Wikipedia's XUL page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XUL), the [BlueGriffon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BlueGriffon) html editor used JavaScript with the same technologies that you have selected.

Comment: So, as I think I need to run XUL pages with scripts, that contain html code and this code will be appear in GeckoWebBrowser, right?